# SQL Server - How can varbinary(max) store > 8000 bytes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2005, varbinary

In SQL Server 2005 and 2008 R2, I'm calling into a stored procedure that has an out parameter defined as `varbinary(max)`. The out parameter returns 10020 bytes according to `DATALENGTH`.

However, SQL Server errors if I try to define a varbinary with > 8000 bytes such as varbinary(10000). E.g.

```
The size (10000) given to the type 'varbinary' exceeds the maximum allowed for any data type (8000).
```

What is happening here? How can SQL Server return more bytes than allowed in the data type? Is SQL Server using some other data type behind the scenes to hold > 8000 bytes?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.  You can define a `varbinary(max)` or a `varbinary(8000)` but you can't define a `varbinary` with a size between 8000 and max (2^31 - 1).  A `varbinary(max)` can have a 10,000 byte value, a `varbinary(8000)` cannot.

Comment: I was thinking that if SQL Server supported up to 2^31 - 1 that you would be able to specify the length to be any positive integer value up to that max. But from your comment, I see that SQL Server just prevents you from defining a varbinary(n) where 8000<n<2^31 -1. Thanks.

Comment: I think this would be good information for developers of SQL Server JDBC drivers:) The drivers truncate data > 8000 bytes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The maximum size you can *specify* is 8000.  Anything larger needs to be specified as `(MAX)`

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx for details.

Comment: Thanks Max. varbinary(max) means you want the possibility of data extending across more than one page. Any size number you set is a size within one page.